# After Creating my React Project.When I made Components and Context folder in src I am getting this error.What should I do?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> CreateContext.text cannot be compiled under '--isolated modules because it is considered a global script file. Add an import, export, or an empty 'export {}' statement to make it a module.

Comment: Please add your relevant code

Answer (score 0):

The file `CreateContext.text` is considered a global script file, which means it is not a module. Are you exporting or importing something in this file? Otherwise, it will keep considering this file as a script and not a module.

You can check the documentation for [isolated modules](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#isolatedModules.) here.

On a side note, you probably shouldn't use `.text` extension for the context file. You can keep using `.js` or `.jsx`.

Comment: I did not use any extension .txt in  my project and I used .jsx